# Two async objects interacting

Tags: python, asynchronous, python-asyncio

I've been exploring how async works in Python. So far, I've made a few simple MQTT-based async mini-services (get a message, do something, maybe retrieve something, send a message).

For my next mini-project, I'm trying to tie Discord and MQTT together. The goal is to have discord messages appear over MQTT, and mqtt messages on discord. I've got an async `discord-client` object, and an async `mqtt-client` object. Both work fine, but connecting them is a bit of an issue.

My current approach is to have the Discord object be 'leading', while I put the MQTT object in the Discord object (`discord-client.mqtt-client = mqtt-client`, meaning I can do things like `await self.mqtt-client.publish()`. This appears to work, so far.

My problem is that this approach feels a bit wrong. Is this a normal approach? Are there other approaches?

Comment: What is the goal of connecting your two clients? What is the end goal? Presenting a specific problem will make it a lot easier for others to assist.

Comment: Forgot to mention, sorry. The goal is to push messages from discord to mqtt and vice versa.

Comment: That sounds like a good use for `asyncio.Queue`.

Comment: This question doesn't really seem answerable at this point. For one, it asks for some sort of design review based (which is itself out of scope on StackOverflow) based on very little details. It's also not clear whether the current solution "feels wrong" due to a technical concern, such as a corner case that might not be handled, or due to a _design smell_ where everything works fine, but you feel like a different design might improve on the clarity/maintainability of the code.

Comment: @dirn: I seem to have missed `asyncio.Queue` completely, thanks for pointing it out!
It does make for a more clear design, both in code and in diagram; instead of having two objects, where one contains the other, I now have two separate objects, both with two `Queue` objects.
@user4815162342: design smell is the better term here. When something smells wrong, it probably is, but I couldn't put my finger on what it was exactly, or how to proceed from here.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question, with help.

Having nested async objects works, but 'smells wrong'. It also makes for odd looking (and therefore difficult to maintain) code, and likely introduces weird bugs and such later on.

A better approach is to make use of `asyncio.Queue`, where each of the two client-objects has one queue to write to, and one to read from. Like this:

`discord-client` -> `discord-to-mqtt-queue` -> `mqtt-client`

`mqtt-client` -> `mqtt-to-discord-queue` -> `discord-client`

(Not the actual naming of the objects)

This works, makes sense, and the resulting code is readable.